# Access SSAS using Excel , Issue with Grand total

Tags: excel, pivot, ssas

In our SSAS cube(MDX), when we view a measure ,individual values for SKU shows as 45,35 but grand total does not show 80 (which is SUM) or 40 (which is AVG) but instead shows the value as 37. Column DSI is a calculated measure where the calculation is a simple division of two measures. Can someone help me understand if this is an expected behavior or if there is an issue with grand total calculation that needs to be corrected?[image: Issue replication here]

Tried using non calculated Measures and the behaviour seems to be fine , the issue seems to come only from Calculated measures

Answer (score 0):

I think we were able to identify the grand total behavior. The grand total was not calculated based on individual DSI values. Instead was getting calculated based on aggregated numerator and denominator values.

E. G. If DSI formula is A/B, values will be calculated as shown below. Here grandtotal is not SUM(45, 35) or AVG(45, 35) instead was SUM(A) / SUM (B) which is 160/4.

| SKU | AValue | BValue | DSI |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SKU1 | 90 | 2 | 45 (90/2) |
| SKU2 | 70 | 2 | 35 (70/2) |
| Grandtotal | 160 | 4 | 40 (160/4) |

Another example that clarifies grand total behavior. If denominator was 0, DSI was defaulted to 9999 in the calculated measure logic. But when Grandtotal DSI was calculated, it was not considered since the sum of denominator will take it's value as 0.

| SKU | AValue | BValue | DSI |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SKU1 | 90 | 2 | 45 (90/2) |
| SKU2 | 70 | 0 | 9999 *Def |
| Grandtotal | 160 | 2 | 80 (160/2) |

Hope this helps.